# Label in UICollectionReusableView displayed only in even indexes

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

I have run into a very odd problem with UICollectionReusableView. My footer's are displaying correctly but the problem is with my headers.

My headers are a subclass of UICollectionReusableView and contain:

- A UILabel on the left side
- A UILabel on the right side

Both labels are initialized the same way with very similar properties in the initWithFrame method which is being correctly called.

Here is an example code section:

```
  - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    if((self = [super initWithFrame:frame]))
    {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectInset(frame, 10, 0)];
        titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:24];
        titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        titleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [self addSubview:titleLabel];

        dotCountLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(2 * frame.size.width / 3 - 5, 8, frame.size.width / 3, frame.size.height)];
        dotCountLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
        dotCountLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        dotCountLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [self addSubview:dotCountLabel];
    }

    return self;
}
```

The second label is being displayed without any problem but the first one in odd indexed sections is displayed on top of the label in the next section. For any of view that would like to see how I create these views:

```
    SaveHeader *header = (SaveHeader *)[collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:kind withReuseIdentifier:@"saveHeader" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    Pattern *pattern = [saveModel.savedPatterns objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    header.titleLabel.text = pattern.title;
    header.dotCountLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i dots", pattern.dotCount];
    return header;
```

I have worked with these a bunch of times before and I have never run into anything like this. Anyone have an idea why this happening and how it could be fixed? Also note I have ran a debugger through it and the data object is returning the correct data. I am using iOS 7.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before your initWithFrame calls, store the CGRect that you are about to init with into a variable and examine it. Look closely at the values. You'll likely find your bug there. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, your answer led me to solving the problem! I used a CGRectMake similar to the second label. Why would frame be the next header though?

Comment: Glad to help. Not sure of the reason why the frame would be incorrect short of incorrect calculations without seeing all the code and stepping through it. You might consider checking this out as well - a very helpful utility: https://github.com/podio/ios-view-frame-builder

Comment: your answer helped me after 2 hours of r&d!